# Deploy and run Offscrub VBS Scripts from Intune silently

Tags: powershell, ms-office, intune

We would like to run the Office Removal VBS scripts on our group of Intune managed Windows 10 machines, aiming to remove all 32bit pre-installed Office products.

So far I've attempted to package all VBS scripts and accompanying Powershell script found on [Github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-IT-Pro-Deployment-Scripts/tree/master/Office-ProPlus-Deployment/Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls) into an exe using IExpress.

Local execution of the exe produces unexpected results, I believe the controlling ps1 script is not being run correctly, or at all for that matter.

Here is the SED file for IExpress:

```html
[Version]
Class=IEXPRESS
SEDVersion=3
[Options]
PackagePurpose=InstallApp
ShowInstallProgramWindow=0
HideExtractAnimation=0
UseLongFileName=0
InsideCompressed=0
CAB_FixedSize=0
CAB_ResvCodeSigning=0
RebootMode=N
InstallPrompt=%InstallPrompt%
DisplayLicense=%DisplayLicense%
FinishMessage=%FinishMessage%
TargetName=%TargetName%
FriendlyName=%FriendlyName%
AppLaunched=%AppLaunched%
PostInstallCmd=%PostInstallCmd%
AdminQuietInstCmd=%AdminQuietInstCmd%
UserQuietInstCmd=%UserQuietInstCmd%
SourceFiles=SourceFiles
[Strings]
InstallPrompt=
DisplayLicense=
FinishMessage=End of Script
TargetName=C:\PowerShellScripts\Remove Office 32bit Installs.EXE
FriendlyName=Remove Office 32bit Installs
AppLaunched=PowerShell.exe -noprofile -Sta -executionpolicy bypass -File Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls.ps1
PostInstallCmd=<None>
AdminQuietInstCmd=
UserQuietInstCmd=
FILE0="OffScrub_O15msi.vbs"
FILE1="OffScrub_O16msi.vbs"
FILE2="OffScrub03.vbs"
FILE3="OffScrub07.vbs"
FILE4="OffScrub10.vbs"
FILE5="OffScrubc2r.vbs"
FILE6="Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls.ps1"
[SourceFiles]
SourceFiles0=C:\PowerShellScripts\
[SourceFiles0]
%FILE0%=
%FILE1%=
%FILE2%=
%FILE3%=
%FILE4%=
%FILE5%=
%FILE6%=
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.